# Using centered div as margin and the excessive use of divs

Tags: html, margin, center

I am fairly new to this and I find myself using divs as drawn margins for the contents inside instead of using padding, something like this:

```html
<div class="container" style="width:100%; height:500px; positon:relative;">
    <div class="subcontainer" style="width:25%; height:100%; position:relative; float:left;">
     <div class="subcontainer" style="width:100%; height:40%; position:relative; overflow:visible;">
      <img src="" style="width:200px; height:200px; position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%; transform:translate(-50%, -50%);">
  </div>
  <div class="subcontainer" style="width:100%; height:60%; position:relative;">
      <div class="marcontainer" style="position:absolute; width:80%; height:80%; top:50%; left:10%; transform:translateY(-50%); text-align:left;">
       <h5>Build a website</h5>
    <h6>You'll learn the basics to building a website with an introduction to text editors, basic HTML tags, and advanced HTML skills.</h6>
    <a href="#"><h6>Leer más</h6></a>
       
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="subcontainer" style="width:25%; height:100%; position:relative; float:left;">
     <div class="subcontainer" style="width:100%; height:40%; position:relative; overflow:visible;">
      <img src="" style="width:200px; height:200px; position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%; transform:translate(-50%, -50%);">
  </div>
  <div class="subcontainer" style="width:100%; height:60%; position:relative;">
      <div class="marcontainer" style="position:absolute; width:80%; height:80%; top:50%; left:10%; transform:translateY(-50%); text-align:left;">
       <h5>Build a website</h5>
    <h6>You'll learn the basics to building a website with an introduction to text editors, basic HTML tags, and advanced HTML skills.</h6>
    <a href="#"><h6>Leer más</h6></a>
       
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="subcontainer" style="width:25%; height:100%; position:relative; float:left;">
     <div class="subcontainer" style="width:100%; height:40%; position:relative; overflow:visible;">
      <img src="" style="width:200px; height:200px; position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%; transform:translate(-50%, -50%);">
  </div>
  <div class="subcontainer" style="width:100%; height:60%; position:relative;">
      <div class="marcontainer" style="position:absolute; width:80%; height:80%; top:50%; left:10%; transform:translateY(-50%); text-align:left;">
       <h5>Build a website</h5>
    <h6>You'll learn the basics to building a website with an introduction to text editors, basic HTML tags, and advanced HTML skills.</h6>
    <a href="#"><h6>Leer más</h6></a>
       
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="subcontainer" style="width:25%; height:100%; position:relative; float:left;">
     <div class="subcontainer" style="width:100%; height:40%; position:relative; overflow:visible;">
      <img src="" style="width:200px; height:200px; position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%; transform:translate(-50%, -50%);">
  </div>
  <div class="subcontainer" style="width:100%; height:60%; position:relative;">
      <div class="marcontainer" style="position:absolute; width:80%; height:80%; top:50%; left:10%; transform:translateY(-50%); text-align:left;">
       <h5>Build a website</h5>
    <h6>You'll learn the basics to building a website with an introduction to text editors, basic HTML tags, and advanced HTML skills.</h6>
    <a href="#"><h6>Leer más</h6></a>
       
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Is this a good practice? It helps me visualize the layout of the page I want to make but I don't know if I am  unnecessarily cluttering things. For me is fine to understand.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, not a good practice because

- Code length  is increased
- readability is reduced
- use of inline styling is also not a good option.

Use only div that make sense as per your page design.

eg. for blog post use div for header/footer/main content area and one each for blog post with styling via class

Comment: Can you explain why I get different results when I use a centered 80% width and height div than when I use paddig:10%?      It should give the same results but it doesn't, is padding broken?